# How to use project in nested array using $In to get Data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to get  to use array for searching data in mongo

Here is my data

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("5f0d6e394556410d486f6828"),
    "branchId": "exampleId",
    "info": [
        {
            "date": "12-10-09",
            "programs": [
                {
                    "programId": "ObjectId1",    
                },
                {
                    "programId": "ObjectId2",    
                },
                {
                    "programId": "ObjectId3",    
                },
          
            ],
        }
    ],
}
```

I want to find programId by using array here is my array

```
const  programIdArr  =  ["ObjectId1","ObjectId2"]
```

I want out put
NOTE : I want to use programIdArr search in mySql we can use something like whereIn

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("5f0d6e394556410d486f6828"),
    "branchId": "exampleId",
    "info": [
        {
            "date": "12-10-09",
            "programs": [
                {
                    "programId": "ObjectId1",    
                },
                {
                    "programId": "ObjectId2",    
                },
            ],
        }
    ],
}
```

Here is what I try to do

```
const program =
        Models.aggregate([
          { $match: { _id: Mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5f0d6e394556410d486f6828') } },
          {
            //for first project I already get where date = 12-10-09
            $project: {
              info: {
                $filter: {
                  input: '$info',
                  as: 'info',
                  cond: { $eq: ['$$info.date', '12-10-09'] },
                },
              },
            },

            // in this project I try to filter programId by using programIdArr It doesn't work
             $project: {
              info: {
                $filter: {
                  input: '$info.programs.programId',
                  as: 'programId',
                  cond: { $in: [programIdArr] },
                },
              },
            },
          },
          { $unwind: { path: '$info' } },
        ])
        .exec()
```

As I read document $in it's return only true of false I try  also try to use $all but It didn't work too.

Comment: "program" is an array which is inside another array "info". Filter is only working within an array, not nested. So first "unwind" info, then use filter, then group it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
   [{
        $match: {
            _id: ObjectId("5f0d6e394556410d486f6828")
        }
    }, {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$info",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
            branchId: 1,
            "info.date": 1,
            "info.programs": {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$info.programs',
                    as: 'p',
                    cond: {
                        $in: ["$$p.programId", ["ObjectId1", "ObjectId2"]]
                    },
                },
            }
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            branchId: {
                $first: "$branchId"
            },
            info: {
                $addToSet: "$info"
            }
        }
    }]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F6cHrz3KGFd)